# Change the language of a mobi file

Tags: macos, ebook, kindle

I converted some German-language ePub files to MOBI, using calibre, in order to read them on my Kindle. The problem is, when reading the resulting file, the Kindle only looks up words in the English dictionary, not the German-English dictionary like it does with all other German books.

Does anyone know of a tool for editing .mobi metadata? I'd prefer a solution for OS X, but I'd be happy with anything that works. I'd also happily use a hex editor, if anyone knows which bits I need to frob.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, it seems like there are two possibilities, one easy, one horrible, but more capable.

How I solved my problem with my ePub files, was to just use Amazon's kindlegen. It creates a .mobi from the .epub file, preserving all the metadata.

The horrible option is mobi2mobi. It's a perl script that has huge numbers of annoying dependancies, but it seems to be the answer to my question, and is your only option if calibre ruined the metadata in your files.

Answer (score 0):

Calibre has an option to set the language:

`ebook-convert infile outfile --language de`